# Importing .xml into Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have a macro code below for Excel 2007. I need to import .xml files into Excel. There are 1,000 .xml files. The schema is only 80 percent the same. I need to import them to Excel and export them as .csv with semicolon.
I have inserted the code into Excel macro. But when I execute it the files are not being imported.

Can any one help me check the code, will the code work for my scenario?

```vb
Sub From_XML_To_XL_02
On Error GoTo errh
Dim myWB As Workbook, WB As Workbook
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim myPath
  myPath = "C:\WorkFolder\Projects\"
Dim myFile
  myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xml")
Dim t As Long, N As Long, r As Long, c As Long
  t = 1
  N = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While myFile <> ""
   N = N + 1
   Set WB = Workbooks.OpenXML(FileName:=myPath & myFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
   If N > 1 Then
        r = WB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        c = WB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        WB.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(3, "A"), Cells(r, c)).Copy myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(t, "A")
   Else
      WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(t, "A")
  End If
WB.Close False
t = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
myFile = Dir()
  Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  myWB.Save
Exit Sub
errh:
 MsgBox "no files xml"
End Sub
```

Comment: People are more likely to help if you *indent your code* - it's difficult to read as-posted.

Comment: `FileName:=myPath & myFile` - here `myPath` has no terminating backslash, so this doesn't form a usable path.  Comment out the error handler and see what errors you get.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. will make the update and get back to you.

Comment: On the Data tab >> Get External Data >> From other sources >> From XML data import

Record a macro and ,analyze the code as well as check whether import is successful.

Comment: Your program with some corrections works fine on my computer. Please look carefully changes in paths made at the last minute to conform to paths mentioned in your post.

Comment: Is your program working now or still there are some problems.

Comment: Hi Skkakkar. Just came back from a short trip.. Will check it today and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code, now it works and saves files such as File1.xls, File2.xls etc. Changes have been marked on your code. Still one minor problem remains that last file though saved remains open in the workspace. This I could not examine further due to my pre-occupation with some other things. I hope you will be able to resolve this issue. Modified code as follows.

```vb
 Sub From_XML_To_XL_02
    On Error GoTo errh
    Dim myWB As Workbook, WB As Workbook
    Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim myPath
    myPath = "C:\WorkFolder\Projects\"
    Dim myFile
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xml")
    Dim t As Long, N As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    t = 1
    N = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(myFile) > 0             'Do While myFile <> ""
     N = N + 1
      Set WB = Workbooks.OpenXML(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFile)   ' Set WB = Workbooks.OpenXML(FileName:=myPath & myFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
       If N > 1 Then
        r = WB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        c = WB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        WB.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(3, "A"), Cells(r, c)).Copy myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(t, "A")
        Else
        WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(t, "A")
      End If
                                     'WB.Close False
      t = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    myWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\WorkFolder\Projects\Files" & N & ".xls" 'added save path here to save in different files
    WB.Close False
    myFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    myWB.Save
Exit Sub
 errh:
 MsgBox "no files xml"
 End Sub
```